# How to run both sorting and filtering on mongodb server with c# code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've found c# code like this (`Collection` is of type `MongoCollection<T>` here):

```
Collection.AsQueryable()
   .OrderByDescending(i => i.SomeField)
   .Where(i => i.OtherField == "bla-bla")
```

does not run both sorting (OrderBy) and filtering (Where) on a server as I expected, instead it calls sorting with MongoDb engine and all further filtering is processed on a client side, which takes fair amount of time. That what I've found in Mongodb profiler as a result of the code execution:

```
"query" : {
    "$query" : { },
    "$orderby" : {
       "SomeField" : -1
    }
 }
```

Note `$query` is empty. Well, is there any idea over how to make it work on database (both sorting and filtering)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order the items, all have to be retrieved, so if you specify that as the first operation I'd expect the behaviour you observed. So you'd have to reverse your statement (as you do in the `IMongoQuery` syntax). This can also be done in LINQ syntax, but since `Where` returns `IEnumerable`, you need an extra cast:

```
Collection.AsQueryable()
   .Where(i => i.OtherField == "bla-bla").AsQueryable()
   .OrderByDescending(i => i.SomeField)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the resolution I've just found might look like this:

```
Collection.Find(
  Query.And(Query.EQ("OtherField", "bla-bla")).
  SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("SomeField").ToList()
```

It builds exactly what I need:

```
"query" : {
    "$query" : {
       "OtherField" : "bla-bla"
     },
    "$orderby" : {
       "SomeField" : -1
     }
 }
```

However I do not quite like this approach as it makes me to hardcode database field names. Presumably new c# driver 1.6 will let you build same queries using delegates like `i => i.OtherField == "bla-bla"`.

Any other approaches?